# How to use data stored in register when calling scanf in nasm assembly

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-64, calling-convention

In the following, I'm trying to get the user's choice and use it to call other functions. I'm pushing choice onto the stack, then pushing the format line, then calling scanf, but I can't seem to be able to use what was entered.

```
;nasm -f elf64 fib.asm -o fib.o
;gcc -S -masm=intel fib.c -o fib.s
;./fib

    bits 64
    global  main
    extern  puts
extern  printf
extern  scanf

section .data
errormsg:   db  'Invalid Input. Enter N,F, or X',0x0D,0x0a,0
numequalsmsg:   db  'Number equals: '
LC2:    db  "%d",0

menuprompt: db  0x0D,0x0a,'Enter N to enter an integer from 0 to 20',0x0D,0x0a,'Enter F to display the first N+1 numbers (beginning with zero) on the console',0x0D,0x0a,'Enter X to quit the program',0x0D,0x0a,0
choicemsg:  db  "Your Choice: ",0
LC5:    db  "%s",0
enterintmsg:    db  "Enter and integer 0-20: ",0
enternummsg:    db  'Enter a valid number between 0 and 20',0x0D,0x0a,0

LC8:    db  " , ",0
LC9:    db  'Success!',0x0D,0x0a,0
LC10:   db  'In L10!',0x0D,0x0a,0       
LC11:   db  'In L12!',0x0D,0x0a,0 
LC13:   db  'In compare to zero section',0x0D, 
value:  dw  0
choice: dw  0


section .text
main:

menu:
    push    rbp
    mov rbp, rsp
    sub rsp, 16

    mov edi, menuprompt
    call    puts            ;display menu
    mov edi,choicemsg
    mov eax, 0
    call    printf          ;display "Your choice: "    
    ;call   getn    

    push choice
    push LC5        ;string format
    call scanf      ;stores input in choice
    ;GetLInt     [choice]
    mov ebx, choice
    cmp ebx, 78
    je  correct

correct:
    mov edi, ebx
    mov eax,0
    call    printf
```

(editor's note: `section.data` is just a label declaration like `foo.bar:`, and so is `.code`.  Probably you wanted `section .data` and `section .text` instead of having everything in the read-only `.text` section, since you want scanf to store a result there.  I fixed this for you because this old question and the answer weren't about those errors.)

Comment: You probably want `mov bl, [choice]` - only a single byte.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info for info on using gdb with assembly, in case you didn't have a good debugging setup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the wrong convention. Obviously you know what you should do, since you had no problem calling `printf`. You should use the same convention for calling `scanf` too - the stack argument passing that you used is the 32 bit convention, 64 bit uses registers. Something like this:

```
lea rdi, [LC5]    ; 1st arg = format
lea rsi, [choice] ; 2nd arg = address of buffer
xor eax, eax      ; no xmm registers
call scanf        ; stores input in choice
```

By the way, using an unconstrained `%s` with 2 bytes of space is a bad idea.

Also, do what Frank said, ie. load a byte (`mov bl, [choice]`) when you want to process the input.

Comment: Changed it to %d and and trying co see if the user entered 'N' by typing cmp    BYTE [choice], 78       also have the same command comparing to 70 and 88. For some reason it shows all of the possible jump to functions even though each number (or letter rather) should jump to a different one. If I replace [choice] with [bl] I get invalid effective address. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you use `%d` then `scanf` will expect a number, and `N` is not a number so you won't have any result. Also, `%d` would then require a 4 byte integer.